# forloop.last not working in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

forloop.last is not working as expected. It is actually working as if it belonged to the outermost forloop. When the last visit is printed the last comma in the last  is not showing.

My code is this:

```
  <tbody>
        {% for visit in SiteVisits  %}
            <tr>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>Other Data</td>
                <td>More Data</td>
                <td>{% for person in people %}
                        {% if person.actionid == visit.actionid %}
                            {{ person.firstname }}
                            {{ person.personlastname }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Is this a bug in Django or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the last `person` in loop has `person.actionid != visit.actionid`.  So the check for `forloop.last` is not executed.